# Trying to call method from MainActivity in Another Activity it is me leading to error

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have Recycler ListView which I show in MainActivity and the first item it is as selected, I have done to click for another items but the last stays clicked and when I try to take this recycler view to show me in next Activity it doesn't work.

The first item it is selected but I have a click method which when click an image makes as selected but when I click a new image this works but the first item stays as selected so continues for others images. I want only a image to be selected.

I don't want to write twice the same code.
Is it good if I have a class only for this method which I can use everytime I want.
The id of recycler view list it is the same on both xml's.
If you have any suggestion for my question please let me know.

This is the adapter for the RecyclerView.

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    private int selectedItem;

    private ArrayList<Integer> mImages = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mSearchUrl = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;

    public ListViewAdapter(ArrayList<Integer> images, ArrayList<String> SearchUrl, Context context) {
        mImages = images;
        mContext = context;
        mSearchUrl = SearchUrl;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.s_engine_item, viewGroup, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        selectedItem = 0;
        if (selectedItem == i) {
            viewHolder.image.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#30000000"));
        }
        Glide.with(mContext).load(mImages.get(i))
                .into(viewHolder.image);
       viewHolder.searchUrl.setText(mSearchUrl.get(i));

       viewHolder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               viewHolder.image.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#30000000"));
               selectedItem = i;


           }
       });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mImages.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView image;
        TextView searchUrl;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivEngine);
        searchUrl = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivEngineText);
    }
}
}
```

This is the method in MainActivity.class

```
public void intSearch() {
    mImages.add(R.drawable.s_bing);
    mSearchUrl.add("https://www.bing.com/search?q=");

    mImages.add(R.drawable.s_google);
    mSearchUrl.add("https://www.google.com/search?q=");

    mImages.add(R.drawable.s_yahoo);
    mSearchUrl.add("www.yahoo.com");

    mImages.add(R.drawable.amazon_white256);
    mSearchUrl.add("www.amazon.com");

    mImages.add(R.drawable.amazon_white256);
    mSearchUrl.add("www.amazon.com");

    mImages.add(R.drawable.amazon_white256);
    mSearchUrl.add("www.amazon.com");

    initRecyclerView();
}
private void initRecyclerView() {
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.lvEngines);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(mImages, mSearchUrl, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

This is the button which takes to another activity.

```
btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String newEntry = searchPlugin.getText().toString();
            Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();
                AddHistory(newEntry);
                getFragmentRefreshListener().onRefresh();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivitySearchEngine.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", newEntry);
                intent.putExtra("test", mSearchUrl.get(0));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

        }
    });
```

This is the another activity

```
public class ActivitySearchEngine extends Activity implements 
SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
public ImageView mHome;
public EditText searchPlugin;
public WebView webView;
Button btnSearch;
public ImageButton clearSearch, exitButton;
public ImageView favIcon;
public ProgressBar loadIcon;
String text;
SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;
DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;

private String selectedName;
private int selectedID;
private String selectedSearchUrl;
RecyclerView mListView;
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_result);
    mHome = findViewById(R.id.imgBtnHome);
    searchPlugin = findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    clearSearch = findViewById(R.id.btnClearSearch);
    btnSearch = findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    favIcon = findViewById(R.id.imgViewFavIcon);
    loadIcon = findViewById(R.id.progressBarIcon);
    exitButton = findViewById(R.id.imgBtnStopLoad);
    refreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.refreshLayout);
    mListView = findViewById(R.id.lvEngines);
    refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    mainActivity.intSearch(); // Here it is the error 
Activity.ActivitySearchEngine}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference

    Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
    selectedName = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("name");
    selectedID = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("id",-1); //NOTE: -1 is just the default value
    selectedSearchUrl = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("test");

    searchPlugin.setText(selectedName);
    loadIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("www.bing.com/search?=" + selectedName);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedIcon(WebView view, Bitmap icon) {
            super.onReceivedIcon(view, icon);
            favIcon.setImageBitmap(icon);
        }
    });
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            loadIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            favIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            try {
                if (loadIcon.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    loadIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    favIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mHome.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    exitButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    clearSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    favIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            onRefresh();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });



            searchPlugin.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            processButtonByTextLength();
        }
    });


    mHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            searchPlugin.setText(null);
            finish();
        }
    });

    clearSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            searchPlugin.setText("");
        }
    });

public void processButtonByTextLength() {
    String inputText = searchPlugin.getText().toString();
    if(inputText.length() > 0)        {
        btnSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mHome.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        clearSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        favIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        loadIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        exitButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if(inputText.length() == 0) {
        btnSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mHome.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        clearSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    webView.reload();
    refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}
```

}

This is the photo with RecyclerView at MainActivity.class
[image]

Photo of another Activity
[image]

Comment: You can't directly instantiate Activities, and you can't directly call methods on them.

Comment: @TheWanderer what do you suggest me to do to have the same list view in another activity?

Comment: You need to either restart the activity using an intent and call the appropriate methods on the “onNewIntent” or “onCreate” method, or use a Broadcast Receiver to handle the broadcasting and handling of what you require

Comment: @Brandon do you have any idea with Broadcast Receiver or with another what did you write ?

Comment: `Activity` instance is handled by system itself you should read about component before using one . Here is a [Suggestion](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity).

Comment: @ADM Thank you, what is the best way to use for example a `RecyclerListView` in different Activities ?

Comment: @Spritzig what is it you’re trying to do with the two activities? Is the second activity simply showing more details on the screen? I would look at your layouts and figure out a better way to display this, as I see it, activities are for navigation, fragments are for information, do you really need to use two activities to do what you require?

Comment: @Brandon In my second Activity I have a layout which is for `WebView` but the `WebView` depends from the RecyclerViewList which is in the top of the app.
If it is other way to do easy and not so much code than I do not need activities.

Comment: Have the webView on the first activity, simply make it Invisible or gone until the button is pressed or data is allocated, therefore you shouldn’t need to worry about a second activity (by using webView.setVisible(GONE); )

Comment: @Brandon The first activity does not have any WebView, only the second activity has WebView in the layout.